# Python - Finding when two strings become different

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I am trying to extract product line names from a list of product names. This would be a subset of the product name and is always going to be from the beginning of the string to an arbitrary point where the name lists the variations within the product line such as size, color, etc. This is very easy for a human to do, but the volume of data begs for this to be automated.

Ex data:

```
item_id        description
100            SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue SM 
101            SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue M
200            Acme Gloves Pink X Large
201            Acme Gloves Pink Small 100 Pack
202            Acme Gloves White X Large
203            Acme Gloves White Small
```

Desired Output:

```
item_id        family
100            SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue
101            SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue
200            Acme Gloves Pink
201            Acme Gloves Pink
202            Acme Gloves White
203            Acme Gloves White
```

Approach:
Iterate through the rows, iterating through each description string, comparing each time to the description of the last item, and stopping if the description changes. When it does change from the last description and its over 10 chars into the string, it backs up one position and calls that the family name. It also applies that to the previous item since it was the first in the family and had nothing to compare with other than a non-matching string. For each new description, I make sure it is very similar to the last one with SequenceMatcher to reset when the data goes to a new product family.

I am open to suggestions on better ways to do this. My code does not work well and leaves artifacts on the end of the strings. The actual data is hugely varied, but most product lines have a common start to their description that should be able to be extracted to make the family name.

Code (Python 2.7 on Win10):

```
import os
import csv
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

items = []
descs = []
families = {}

with open('items_no_family.csv', 'rb') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        items.append(row['item_id'])
        descs.append(row['description'])

i = 0
last_desc = ''
for d in descs:
    p = 1
    print items[i] + ' ' + d
    if last_desc != '':
        seq = SequenceMatcher(None, last_desc, d)
        if seq.ratio() >= 0.9:
            for c in d:
                if d[0:p] != last_desc[0:p] and p > 10:
                    families[items[i]] = d[0:p-1]
                    families[items[i-1]] = d[0:p-1]
                    break
                p = p + 1
    last_desc = d
    i = i + 1

with open("items w families.csv", "ab") as f:
    for k,v in families.items():
        f.write(k + ',"' + v +'"\r\n')
```

Comment: Sorry, gotta ask: Python 2 is *dead*. It's also a bad idea for general text parsing (because it's hard to make it handle non-ASCII properly, and when you do, it's a lot slower and more memory intensive than Py3). Why are you writing new code in it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain my idea:
You set a threshold value, which means how many character should overlap at least to define a new family, and assume that every product has a family.
By doing so you store every new product as a new family. When a new product overlap with a family for more than **threshold** characters you shrink the family name so that the two products now are in that family

```
    products = [
"SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue SM ",
"SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue M",
"Acme Gloves Pink X Large",
"Acme Gloves Pink Small 100 Pack",
"Acme Gloves White X Large",
"Acme Gloves White Small"
]

families = list()
ifam = list() #index of the family
threshold = 15 #at least 15 characters should be equals


for prod in products:
    if len(prod) < threshold: continue
    check = False
    for j in range(len(families)):
        fam = families[j]
        if prod[:threshold] == fam[:threshold]:
            check = True #product has an already existed category
            for i in range(min(len(prod),len(fam))):

                if prod[i] != fam[i]:
                    families[j] = fam[:i] #keep only the same characters
                    ifam.append(j) #product[i] is in the j family
                    break
            ifam.append(j)    
            break
    if not check:
        families.append(prod) #this product will be used for a category

#let me see the families
for i in range(len(products)):
    print("product: \"%s\" is in the family: \"%s\"" % (products[i],families[ifam[i]]))
```

If you want to use this code, remember that you have to choose which threshold value is better for you, and how to deal with products which name is shorter than the threshold

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pairwise()` from `itertools` and use a stack to detect where the strings change:

```
import itertools

brands = ["SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue SM ",
          "SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue M",
          "Acme Gloves Pink X Large",
          "Acme Gloves Pink Small 100 Pack",
          "Acme Gloves White X Large",
          "Acme Gloves White Small"]


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

table = []
for pair in pairwise(brands):
    stack = ""
    for x, y in zip(pair[0], pair[1]):
        if x == y:
            stack += x
        else:
            if stack:
                trunk = stack
            break
    table.append((trunk.rstrip(), pair[0]))

print(table)
```

This yields

```
[
    ('SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue', 'SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue SM '),
    ('SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue', 'SomeBrand Medical Jackets Blue M'),
    ('Acme Gloves Pink', 'Acme Gloves Pink X Large'),
    ('Acme Gloves', 'Acme Gloves Pink Small 100 Pack'),
    ('Acme Gloves White', 'Acme Gloves White X Large')
]
```